# MongoDB 32 bit GUI client

Tags: mongodb

I need a MongoDB GUI client to see my mongodb database on my local computer but i cannot find any 32 bit version. Can someone link any client except Navicat 15 for MongoDB

My `MongoDB shell version: 3.2.22`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these Open Source Tools

- [MongoUI](https://github.com/azat-co/mongoui)
  A Open Source Node Web GUI for Mongo DB.
- [Nosqlclient](https://github.com/nosqlclient/nosqlclient)
  (Formerly Mongoclient), MongoDB Management Tool. Runs with Docker.

Or if you if you also look for paid software you can check out:

- [humongous](https://www.humongous.io)
  A Secure and Modern Online MongoDB GUI.
- [Acho](https://acho.io)

StackOverflow isn't the best place to search for a tool. Maybe you better check out the tools listed on:
[Alternativeto.net/Mongodb-Compass](https://alternativeto.net/software/mongodb-compass/)